# Piping Given an Array of UNIX Commands

Tags: c, shell, unix, piping

So I am at the very end of a project to create a basic UNIX shell using C.  I have finished a lot of different pieces of the program, but now I would like to conquer piping.  I would specifically like to create a program that can handle **any number** of pipes.

For some reason my code get to s certain line (labeled: **//DIES HERE**) and then stops and I can't figure out why.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
//the contents of args[0] is {"ls","-l","-o"}
//the contents of args[1] is {"wc","-l"}

int pipefd[2];

pipe(&pipefd[0]);   // Error check!

fflush(stdout);
for (i = 0; i < commands; i++){
    int pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0){

        int command_no = i;
        int prev_pipe = ((command_no - 1) % 2) * 2;
        int current_pipe = (command_no % 2) * 2;
        printf("\ncmd %d: prev pipe %d, curr pipe %d\n\n", i, prev_pipe, current_pipe);
        fflush(stdout);

        // If current command is the first command, close the
        // read end, else read from the last command's pipe
        if (command_no == 0){
            close(pipefd[0]);
        }
        else{
            dup2(pipefd[prev_pipe], 0);
            close(pipefd[current_pipe]);                    
        }

        // If current command is the last command, close the
        // write end, else write to the pipe
        if (command_no == commands - 1){
            close(pipefd[current_pipe + 1]);                    
        }
        else{
            dup2(pipefd[current_pipe + 1], 1); //DIES HERE
        }
        // printf("Here?\n\n");
        execvp(*args[i], args[i]);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to exec: %s (%d: %s)\n", arrayOfCommands[i], errno, strerror(errno));
        _exit(1);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: If execvp() fails you should exit( non-zero-number). 0 is used to show success in Unix.

Comment: Don't forget about putting all the piped processes in one process group (with the first process as a process group leader). This allows you to wait for the whole group to end (see 'waitpid' or even better 'waitid' function). I would suggest looking at bash source code. Not only that: comile bash in debug mode and debug it while running: it will open your eyes on many many things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue I see is that `pipe()` is outside the loop.  You're going to need a new `pipe()` between every pair of processes.  The comments on your question make some good points as well.

I wrote a shell many years ago in college and here's the similar loop from my code.  I'm sure I'd do it much differently now, but it may be of use to you:

```
    for (i = 0; i < iNumPipes; ++i) {
            if (i == iNumPipes - 1) {
                    /* this is the last command
                     */
                    p[1] = fdOutput;
                    p[0] = -1;
            } else if (-1 == pipe(p)) {
                    perror("pipe");
                    exit(1);
            }

            switch (iPid = fork()) {
            case -1:
                    perror("fork");
                    exit(1);
            case 0:
                    close(0);
                    dup2(fdInput, 0);
                    close(fdInput);

                    close(1);
                    dup2(p[1], 1);
                    close(p[1]);

                    if (-1 != fdErr) {
                            close(2);
                            dup2(fdErr, 2);
                            close(fdErr);
                    }

                    pc = SearchPath(pppcAvs[i][0]);
                    execve(pc, pppcAvs[i], ppcEnv);
                    perror(pc);
                    _exit(-1);
            default:
                    close(fdInput);
                    close(p[1]);
                    fdInput = p[0];
            }

    }
```

Comment: This is great!  Would you mind sharing what fdErr is?  I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Comment: Actually, better yet, would you mind sharing how fdOutput, fdInput, and fdErr are defined?

Comment: They are all file descriptors (hence the `fd` prefix since I was into Hungarian notation at the time) so they are `int`.  The shell had peculiar redirect rules for `stderr` so `fdErr` is the "global" error redirect.  The `fdOutput` and `fdInput` just tie the hops of the chain together.  Before that loop they're just set to `dup(0)` and `dup(1)` unless there were file redirects on the command line.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I'm still having a hard time making your code work, mostly because I am fairly new to C and especially to pipes.  Could you give me a "for dummies" explanation of how to set up fdOutput, fdInput, and fdErr?

Comment: just `int fdInput = dup(0)` and `int fdOutput = dup(1)`.  You can also set `int fdErr = dup(2)`.  You can replace any of those with `open(...)` if you want files instead